# Woocommerce: Checkout not working

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

My problem is that after completing the billing details, if you click continue nothing happens. It´s like if the href is set to ´#´. How should I edit this template so that the user  gets the billing options (Bank transfer and Credit Card gateways) enabling him to complete the order checkout?.

I have already completed the Info required for bank transfer.

[Here´s the Checkout page where the shopping process gets stuck](http://xpressrendering.com/checkout/)

Comment: Since it is a paid theme, it might be easier to contact the developers of the theme for an answer

Comment: I just tried the link and it seems like it works well now. What happens?

Comment: @HaoyuChen If you click the link´s continue button after completing the billing details the process freezes.

Comment: @Howlin, But I think I´m missing some configuration on the Woocommerce side..

Comment: @Gonpires I still don't quite get it.It's hard for others to understand your questions with this link. Maybe it would be better to add a GIF image. You could record it by using a software named recordit(http://recordit.co/)

Comment: @Gonpires The issue is with your payment gateway - what happens if you allow Cash On Delivery as a payment type and select that?

Comment: I´ve just downloaded it but couldn´t execute it in Windows. The point is that if you enter the link and complete the billing details, when you click on continue at the bottom of the form, the webpage freezes. @HaoyuChen

Comment: @doublesharp, Just allowed Cash On Delivery. If you check, the process is still freezing after you complete the billing details and try to continue..

Comment: Try it in Chrome with Developer Tools open and look for an XHR request - there is probably an error coming back in the response. Also check the PHP error log.

Comment: What payment portal are you trying to use?

Comment: It´s a theme issue. I tried using another WP theme and the process goes all the way. I´ll try to figure it out. @doublesharp

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : Check your Php version

Step 2 : Add this line to wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Step 3 : Goto wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php

Step 4 : Goto 34th line in above file

Step 5 : Replace that line

```
return esc_url_raw( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ajax_get_endpoint', add_query_arg( 'wc-ajax', $request, remove_query_arg( array( 'remove_item', 'add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart' ), home_url( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) ) ), $request ) );

return esc_url_raw( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ajax_get_endpoint', add_query_arg( 'wc-ajax', $request, remove_query_arg( array( 'remove_item', 'add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart' ), home_url( '/' ) ) ), $request ) );
```

That's all. Check your Store. Happy Coding...!!!

Comment: in which function i put this code ?
return esc_url_ra ..